# Unable to create partition in 32GB sd card due to problem in Partition Table?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, sd-card

I was trying to create 26GB fat32 partition & 6GB ext4 Partition in my new samsung 32Gb sd card by using Gparted.

but gparted ended in error.The last step formatting the partition as fat32 ended as error.

[my Micro Sd Card's current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO5nc.png)

I tried Gparted , kde partition Manager, fdisk , gdisk , gparted
all them can create corrupted GPT or msdos & allowed me to create partition.
which didn't last after removing & inserting sd card again

back to level one
 no partition table

someone please help me to solve the problem
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Sounds like your card is good for the bin...

Comment: @fkraiem not necessarily

Answer (score 0):

Well I suggest use `fdisk` again for making partition and then `mkfs` for making file system . About lable problem I can say that If your partition will going to be a Linux partition so `e2lable` or `tune2fs -L` commands can help you change partition label .
for making partition flow these steps :

1. `$ fdisk /dev/sdb`
2. then press **p** for list partition . Then **n** , **p** , sector , size . Then press **p** again if you can see your partition or not . Then use **t** for changing partition type ( Ext , NTFS , ... ) . Press **w** to write with ioctl .
3. `$ mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1` which make file system on your partition . ( Replace *ext3* with any partition type you made ) .

Then you can add partition label with `e2label` command . see `man e2label` .